# Trying to combine two queries with SUMs from different date ranges together

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to add the second query's summed columns from the last year's date range, to the end of the first query's results for last month's date range. Is this possible? Thank you!

```
declare @startmm DATE;
declare @endmm DATE;
declare @startyy DATE;
declare @endyy DATE;

set @startmm = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2));
set @endmm = EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1);

set @startyy = DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0));
set @endyy = DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0));


select TRS.F1148 AS 'Member Number',
MAX(CLT.F1149) as 'First Name',
MAX(CLT.F1150) as 'Last Name',
SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.F1034 = 3 THEN TRS.F65 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Month SMS Net Sales',
SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.F1034 = 9 THEN TRS.F65 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Month Member Discount'
from RPT_CLT_D TRS
join CLT_TAB CLT on TRS.F1148=CLT.F1148
join TLZ_TAB TLZ on TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
left outer join CLG_TAB CLG on CLT.F1154=CLG.F1154
join LNK_TAB LNK on TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and LNK.F1057='901' and LNK.F1000='PAL'
where TRS.F254 between @startmm and @endmm
group by TRS.F1148
order by TRS.F1148 ASC;



select TRS.F1148 AS 'Member Number',
MAX(CLT.F1149) as 'First Name',
MAX(CLT.F1150) as 'Last Name',
SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.F1034 = 3 THEN TRS.F65 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year SMS Net Sales',
SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.F1034 = 9 THEN TRS.F65 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Member Discount'
from RPT_CLT_D TRS
join CLT_TAB CLT on TRS.F1148=CLT.F1148
join TLZ_TAB TLZ on TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
left outer join CLG_TAB CLG on CLT.F1154=CLG.F1154
join LNK_TAB LNK on TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and LNK.F1057='901' and LNK.F1000='PAL'
where TRS.F254 between @startyy and @endyy
group by TRS.F1148
order by TRS.F1148 ASC;
```

Comment: Side note: `BETWEEN` is probably a bad idea on date columns which have a time component. See https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using conditional aggregation to aggregate "SMS Net Sales" and "Member Discount" values separately.

You can just use the same technique.

Change the `WHERE` clause to cover both ranges

```
WHERE  TRS.F254 BETWEEN @startyy AND @endyy
        OR TRS.F254 BETWEEN @startmm AND @endmm
```

And add all four of the desired columns to the `SELECT` list with an additional filter on date

```
SUM(IIF(TRS.F1034 = 3 AND TRS.F254 between @startmm and @endmm, TRS.F65, 0)) AS "Last Month SMS Net Sales",
SUM(IIF(TRS.F1034 = 9 AND TRS.F254 between @startmm and @endmm, TRS.F65, 0)) AS "Last Month Member Discount",
SUM(IIF(TRS.F1034 = 3 AND TRS.F254 between @startyy and @endyy, TRS.F65, 0)) AS "Last Year SMS Net Sales",
SUM(IIF(TRS.F1034 = 9 AND TRS.F254 between @startyy and @endyy, TRS.F65, 0)) AS "Last Year Member Discount",
```

If you want to only include `F1148` (!) groupings that have an entry in the last month you can also add a

```
 HAVING MAX(IIF(TRS.F254 between @startmm and @endmm, 1, 0)) = 1
```